# Numbers displayed in Discussion List Categories don't add up

Tags: 2013, discussion-board

When we look at the little boxes that preview the amount of replies and discussions in a SharePoint 2013 Discussion List we noticed that sometimes the numbers just don't add up. As you can see in this example there are clearly more than 3 discussions / 15 replies:

[image]

Is there a way to reset these counters or make them display the correct numbers (Timer Job?)? Any help is appreciated.